# Complex Beautiful Soup query

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here is a snippet of an HTML file I'm exploring with Beautiful Soup.

```
<td width="50%">
    <strong class="sans"><a href="http:/website">Site</a></strong> <br />
```

I would like to get the `<a href>` for any line which has the `<strong class="sans">` and which is inside a `<td width="50%">`.

Is it possible to query a HTML file for those multiple conditions using Beautiful Soup ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

BeautifulSoup's search mechanisms accept a callable, which the docs appear to recommend for your case: "If you need to impose complex or interlocking restrictions on a tag's attributes, pass in a callable object for name,...". (ok... they're talking about attributes specifically, but the advice reflects an underlying spirit to the BeautifulSoup API).

If you want a one-liner:

```
soup.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name == 'a' and \
tag.findParent('strong', 'sans') and \
tag.findParent('strong', 'sans').findParent('td', attrs={'width':'50%'}))
```

I've used a lambda in this example, but in practice you may want to define a callable function if you have multiple chained requirements as this lambda has to make two `findParent('strong', 'sans')` calls to avoid raising an exception if an `<a>` tag has no `strong` parent. Using a proper function, you could make the test more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup("""<html><td width="50%">
...     <strong class="sans"><a href="http:/website">Site</a></strong> <br />
... </html>""" )
<html><td width="50%">
<strong class="sans"><a href="http:/website">Site</a></strong> <br />
</td></html>
>>> [ a for a in strong.findAll("a") 
            for strong in tr.findAll("strong", attrs = {"class": "sans"}) 
                for tr in soup.findAll("td", width = "50%")]
[<a href="http:/website">Site</a>]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc = """<td width="50%">
<strong class="sans"><a href="http:/website">Site</a></strong> <br /> 
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
soup.select('td[width="50%"] .sans [href]')
# Out[24]: [<a href="http:/website">Site</a>]
```

[Documentation](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/basic/)