# Beautiful Soup Query with Multiple Attributes in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to find these sections of HTML, but only the ones of a certain month (04), as differentiated by the end of a link.

```
<td class="">
    <div class="dayContainer">
        <a href="/parks/magic-kingdom/calendardayview/?asmbly_day=20120402"> 
            <p class="day"> 2</p> 
            <p class="moreLink">
                Park Hours
                <br />
                8:00 AM - 1:00 AM
                <br /><br/>
                Extra Magic Hours
                <br />
                7:00 AM - 8:00 AM
                <br /><br/>
            </p> 
        </a> 
    </div>
</td>
```

I can find all of the dates by using `findAll('div', attrs={'class':'dayContainer'})`, but that gives me all the dates within the site. I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706443/complex-beautiful-soup-query) example, but everything I tried left me with blank results. Here's what I have now to find the sections:

```
days = soup.findAll(lambda date: date.name == 'a' and date.text[-4:-2] == '04' and date.findParent('div', attrs={'class':'dayContainer'}))
print days
```

Any idea as to where I'm going wrong? Thanks!
Here's [the site](http://disneyworld.disney.go.com/parks/magic-kingdom/calendar/) if anyone needs it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After looking at the site link you posted, I discovered that the the calendars for every monthly are actually contains in a div named 'month_name2012'.

So for April, you can just do:

```
april_c = soup.find('div', attrs={'id':'april2012'})
parking_apr = april_c.findAll('div', 'dayContainer')
for item in parking_apr:
    print item.text
```

This will give you :

> 1Park Hours8:00 AM - 12:00 AMExtra Magic Hours7:00 AM - 8:00 AMExtra
>   Magic Hours12:00 AM - 3:00 AM
>
> 2Park Hours8:00 AM - 1:00 AMExtra Magic Hours7:00 AM - 8:00 AM
>
> 3Park Hours8:00 AM - 1:00 AMExtra Magic Hours7:00 AM - 8:00 AM
>
> 4Park Hours8:00 AM - 1:00 AMExtra Magic Hours7:00 AM - 8:00 AM
>
> 5Park Hours8:00 AM - 1:00 AMExtra Magic Hours7:00 AM - 8:00 AM
>
> 6Park Hours8:00 AM - 12:00 AMExtra Magic Hours7:00 AM - 8:00 AMExtra
>   Magic Hours12:00 AM - 3:00 AM
>
> 7Park Hours8:00 AM - 1:00 AMExtra Magic Hours7:00 AM - 8:00 AM
>
> 8Park Hours8:00 AM - 12:00 AMExtra Magic Hours7:00 AM - 8:00 AMExtra
>   Magic Hours12:00 AM - 3:00 AM
>
> ....

Comment: Any idea how to pull out each of those items individually, say, to store them in a dictionary?

Comment: @westbyb Using RegEx is the method on top of my head.