# Check if class is equal with one of two strings

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Is it possible to modify this somehow so it could find table with class **class1** **OR** class **class2**?

```
Info = soup.find('table', {'class' :'class1'})
```

Comment: I haven't really used Beautiful Soup much, but maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/706531/1460235) will help. Could you pass in a function that searches for the two classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find_all(self, name=None, attrs={}, recursive=True, text=None, limit=None, **kwargs) 

    Extracts a list of Tag objects that match the given
    criteria.  You can specify the name of the Tag and any
    attributes you want the Tag to have.

    The value of a key-value pair in the 'attrs' map can be a
    string, a list of strings, a regular expression object, or a
    callable that takes a string and returns whether or not the
    string matches for some custom definition of 'matches'. The
    same is true of the tag name.
```

For example:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> text = ''.join('<table class="class{}"></table>'.format(i) for i in range(10))
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
>>> 
>>> soup.find_all("table", {"class": ["class1", "class7"]})
[<table class="class1"></table>, <table class="class7"></table>]
>>> import re
>>> soup.find_all("table", {"class": re.compile("class[17]")})
[<table class="class1"></table>, <table class="class7"></table>]
>>> 
>>> soup.find_all("table", {"class": lambda x: 3*int(x[-1])**2-24*int(x[-1])+17 == -4})
[<table class="class1"></table>, <table class="class7"></table>]
```

[Okay, that last one matches too many, but you get the idea: any bool-returning match function will work.]

Comment: Good thing you didn't actually get the last function right on the first try, or I'd have to give you +2, which is impossible. :)